# Error while creating tables in mysql.connector python -- syntax error code 1064(4200)

Tags: python, mysql, create-table, mysql-connector-python

```
c1.execute(f"create table {sub_table_name1}(srno int, data_name varchar(255), data varchar(255))")
```

the error is

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(srno int, data_name varchar(255), data varchar(255))' at line 1

i swear to god i have no idea what is wrong...i'm still a beginner to python and mysql connection and any help is welcome

Comment: what do you mean? i've tried using the %s method as well, it does not work

Comment: then provide the whole code, your sql code looks ok by itself

Comment: Yeah the sql code was fine...actually what happened is that i couldn't assign the user-inputed value to the variable so that was where the error was

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of your `sub_table_name1` variable at the time you execute that? If it's empty, then I think that error would be expected, because the SQL statement would be:

```
create table (srno int, ...
```

MySQL will see that as a missing name. The way it informs you of the error is to tell you the part of the query at the point it got confused:

> for the right syntax to use near '(srno int, ...

This means when it saw `(srno int, ...` it was expecting something else — I'm guessing it was expecting an identifier for the name of the table, but reached the open parenthesis character instead.

Since you said you are new to python (and perhaps to programming), here's a general tip: **question your assumptions.** You assumed the create table statement had a table name in it. Does it? How would you know? Can you add code to print the SQL statement string after you format it with the variables? Can you add code to print the `sub_table_name1` variable before using it in the string? Of course, you should remove such code after you are done debugging.

> "The most effective debugging tool is still careful thought, coupled
> with judiciously placed print statements."
>
> — Brian Kernighan, "Unix for Beginners" (1979)

That's an old book, but the idea is still true!

Comment: Ahhh...I think this must be it...I didn't think about this at all...Thanks a lot.